# XCode Swift: How to create a Tab Bar between 2 View Controllers, if 1 is already connected with a Split View Controller to another View Controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm new to Xcode, so apologies if I'm making beginner mistakes.

Recently, I downloaded a sample project from a [**`website`**](https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) for Xcode Swift.

It has a split view controller to connect a Table View controller with a View Controller which displays the Chocolate's info.

[image: Click here to view how the sample project's main storyboard looks like.]

I would like to use a Tab Bar Controller to connect the Table View Controller with the a New View Controller. I have tried to embed both of them into individual Navigation Controllers, both of which are connected to the Tab Bar Controller. I have tried to do so as shown below:

[image: Click here to view how I have tried to create a Tab Bar between the Table View Controller and the New View Controller.]

However, whenever I try to launch the app, the app will simply crash. The error message is something related to the Split View Controller, but I'm unsure of what I've done wrong.

Could someone please download the sample project from the link to the website above and try to help me create a Tab Bar between the Table View Controller and the New View Controller?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you provide the error message you get.

Comment: The error is found in this code: detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController (Error message: Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT - Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x103947428) to 'UINavigationController' (0x103946ed8).)
2018-03-18 07:47:47.362810+0800 CandySearch[5882:196517]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I added a navigation controller before the tab bar controller. I then unchecked the box "Shows navigation bar" on the new Navigation Controller so that the navigation bar would not overlap with the navigation controller attached to the Table View Controller.

Thanks to those who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to embed your tabs into your navigation controller. ( Exactly has the sample project, except you have some tabs instead of the tableView Controller?

```
-> Split
    -> Nav
        -> Tabs
            -> Table1
            -> Table2
    -> Nav
        -> Detail
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. When I try to do the above, the app will not crash. However, it replaces the navigation bar and removes the search bar in the Table View Controller. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Could you could try it out on the sample project for me and see if you can find a way to create a Tab Bar between the Table View Controller and New View Controller, while keeping the Search Bar in the Table View Controller? Thank you!